# Console WriteLine(var, var); not displaying second variable?

Tags: c#, console.writeline

I'm writing a little text-based adventure in the console as one of my first projects in C#.

At a certain point, I want to do the following:

```
 Console.WriteLine(intro);
 var name = Console.ReadLine();
 Console.Clear();
 Console.WriteLine(replyOne, name, replyTwo);
```

However, on that last line, only the first variable (replyOne) is displayed. How can I display all the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what's on `replyOne`, but you are using a `Console.WriteLine` overload that takes a *format string* as the first argument and a number of objects for substitution of that format string ([this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aakt1eab(v=vs.110).aspx)). That's what's called [Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET

If what you want to do is concatenate the strings, you can do it in several ways:

1. Pass only one string to `Console.WriteLine`:

   ```
   Console.WriteLine(replyOne + name + replyTwo);
   ```
2. Use a format string... this would use the same overload you are using now, but passing a formatting string for substitution on the first argument:

   ```
   Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", replyOne, name, replyTwo);
   ```
3. Use an interpolated string *(C# 6 and up only)*

   ```
   Console.WriteLine($"{replyOne}{name}{replyTwo}");
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the multi-argument overloads of the `Console.WriteLine` the first parameter is supposed to be a format string, and everything else as a substitution values.

See [`Console.WriteLine Method (String, Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `Console.WriteLine` to output a formatted string the first argument has to be the string that contains the placeholders that define the formatting. So assuming you just want to output the three strings consecutively, you'll need something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", replyOne, name, replyTwo);
```

which will output the three strings separated by spaces.

You can replace the spaces by commas, newlines (`\n`) or tabs (`\t`) to get the formatting you need.

Comment: This puts spaces in the output. There's nothing in the original question to suggest those are desired.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, indeed it does put spaces into the output, I see nothing that indicates they want the output *without* spaces.

Comment: @ChrisF I'd rather expect those to be new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Console.WriteLine(replyOne + name + replyTwo);
```

Or something similar.

As you're calling the method right now, it's treating the `replyOne` value as the *format* for the output, not an individual output item. And of course, your format doesn't have a `{0}` or `{1}` for the format arguments in the call, `name` and `replyTwo`, so they are omitted.

You can just concatenate the output text yourself, as above, as use that as the entire format (without any format arguments at all).

There are, of course, lots of other options for formatting the output. The above fits what you've posted so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}",replyOne,name,replyTwo);
```